# Filtering MongoDB collection by a partial match on a single object in an array

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb

In MongoDB I have a collection of User documents that implement these interfaces:

```js
interface User {
    otherProperties: any;
    education: Education[];
    skills: Skill[];
}

interface Education {
    specialization: string;
    provider: string;
    type: string;
    description: string;
}

interface Skill {
    name: string;
    type: string;
    experience: number;
    description: string;
}
```

I have a filter input that implements this interface:

```js
interface UserFilter {
    education: Partial<Education>[];
    skills: Partial<Skill>[];
}
```

Currently I am able to filter users based on complete matches of education and skills objects using the $elemMatch operator, and this works fine:

```js
const users = await database.users.find({
    $or: {
        skills: {
            $elemMatch: { //repeated for each required match
                name: matcher.name,
                type: matcher.type,
                experience: { $gte: matcher.experience },
            },
        },
        education: { //repeated for each required match
            $elemMatch: {
                specialization: matcher.specialization,
                type: matcher.type,
                provider: matcher.provider,
            },
        }
    }
})
```

however this only matches complete objects, and wont match if the input object is a partial object, e.g. a skill input is missing the name property.

How would I query for Users that have matches for partial Education objects or partial Skill objects?

e.g. an input of

```js
{
    education: [
        {
            specialization: 'computer science' ,
            type: 'undergraduate'
        },
        {
            specialization: 'business' ,
            provider: 'university of york'
        },
    ],
    skills: [
        {
            name: 'c++' ,
            type: 'language'
        },
        {
            name: 'python' ,
            experience: 5,
        },
    ],
}
```

should return a match with this object:

```js
{
    otherProperties: any;
    education: [
        {
            specialization: 'computer science' ,
            type: 'undergraduate',
            provider: 'university of york',
            description: '...'
        },
        {
            specialization: 'business' ,
            provider: 'university of york',
            type: 'undergraduate',
            description: '...'
        },
    ],
    skills: [
        {
            name: 'c++' ,
            type: 'language',
            experience: 5,
            description: '...'
        },
        {
            name: 'python' ,
            experience: 5,
            type: 'language',
            description: '...'
        },
        {
            name: 'html' ,
            experience: 1,
            type: 'language',
            description: '...'
        },
    ],
}
```

but not return a match for this object as it is missing python in its skills:

```js
{
    otherProperties: any;
    education: [
        {
            specialization: 'computer science' ,
            type: 'undergraduate',
            provider: 'university of york',
            description: '...'
        },
        {
            specialization: 'business' ,
            provider: 'university of york',
            type: 'undergraduate',
            description: '...'
        },
    ],
    skills: [
        {
            name: 'c++' ,
            type: 'language',
            experience: 5,
            description: '...'
        },
        {
            name: 'html' ,
            experience: 1,
            type: 'language',
            description: '...'
        },
    ],
}
```

Comment: **1.** It's unclear what you mean by `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`. Provide actual examples. **2.** Wrt _"I can already filter for matches of full child objects with $elemMatch"_ - show what you have tried so far (code) in a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).